# autocomplete ajax on two fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am having trouble executing the following code successfully. I want to get autocomplete data from the server on 1st field (drug1) which is successful. I want that the 2nd field (drugdose1) should return result based on the value of the 1st field (drug1). But I am unable to pass the value of the drug1 to the php file. The firefox debug displays as localhost/lib/searchdose.php?d=&q=xx.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='lib/autocompletefull.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() { 

    $("#drug1").autocomplete('lib/search.php', {
       delay:100,        
        maxItemsToShow: 15,
       minChars:2,
       useCache:false
    });

    $("#drugdose1").autocomplete('lib/searchdose.php', {
       delay:100,
       minChars:2,
       extraParams: { d: $("#drug1").val() }
    });

});

</script>
</head><body>
<p>
<form name="hello">
<input type="hidden" id="testing" value="hi there">
Drug Name: <input type="text" tabindex="1" size="40" name="drug1" id="drug1">
</p>
<p>Drug Dose: <input tabindex="2" type="text" name="drugdose1" id="drugdose1" size="35">
</p>
</form>
```

I am using autocomplete.js from https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete ... I am not using jquery.ui autcomplete ..

Comment: Please note that I am not using autocomplete.js from the [link]https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete[/link] because this is a small sized script as compared to jquery UI autocomplete ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
src = 'lib/searchdose.php';


    $("#drugdose1").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    d: $("#drug1").val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        min_length: 3,
        delay: 300
    });
```

Comment: OP is not using jQuery UI autocomplete.

Comment: How do you know that the person who asked the question is using jquery-ui autocomplete?

Comment: @SalmanA sorry I am guessing he using `lib/autocompletefull.js`.

Comment: The above code doesnt work because I am not using jquery-ui autocomplete ... i am using autocomplete from https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete because its small sized ..

Answer (score 0):

I have sort this problem on my own. Here is the solution:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var dname; 

function newv ()
{
    dname = $("#drug1").val();
    $("#drugdose1").autocomplete('lib/searchdose.php', {
       delay:100,
       maxItemsToShow: 15,
       extraParams: { d:dname },
       minChars:1,
       useCache:false
    });
    alert("Hello");
}

$(function() { 

    $("#drug1").autocomplete('lib/search.php', {
       delay:100,        
       maxItemsToShow: 15,
       minChars:2
    });

});

</script>

</head><body>
<p>
<form name="hello">
<input type="hidden" id="testing" value="hi there">
Drug Name: <input type="text" tabindex="1" size="40" name="drug1" id="drug1" onchange="javascript:newv();">
</p>

<p>Drug Dose: <input tabindex="2" type="text" name="drugdose1" id="drugdose1" size="35">
</p>
</form>
```